# How can I remove an installed application from the Installer Package Database on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, uninstall, installer, package-maker

I'm creating my own installer with PackageMaker. It has been working well for a while but I wanted to test an issue where it removes the files of a previous version even though each new version installs to a different folder. One time, I allowed myself to choose a custom folder to install the app to (it will normally install to the user's home directory).

Now every subsequent installations, even of previous installer versions which I have not modified, are now installed to this custom folder. Apparently this is not a PackageMaker issue but a PackageMaker automatism that checks a previous installation. I may get around this by changing the installer package id but I'd rather not.

**How can I access the Installer Package Database? Where can I find it and how can I modify it?**

This would be helpful in particular to test a "clean" installation on a system that never had the app installed before. Maybe there is an easier way, for example a simple uninstall might do as well.

I'm hoping to be able to manually remove my application from the installed applications list. So far I've only found the installation history in the Receipts directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via Twitter I got the tip to use the `pkgutil` tool. The forget argument removes an entry from the installer database but without removing the actual files:

```
sudo pkgutil --forget com.appname
```

To see a list of package ids use:

```
pkgutil --pkgs
```

or use regexp to show only certain entries:

```
pkgutil --pkgs=com.k*
```